# Remove custom permalink base from CPT custom category and custom tags

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have a 'resources' CPT with 'resources_category' (custom category) and 'resources_term' (custom terms). They are all working, however the category and terms URL's pick up the base permalink slug ('news') which is used for the blog posts.

ie. the following 2 URL's are working

*/resources/*
*/resources/post-title/*

however the taxonomy URL's are

*/news/resources/category/videos/*
*/news/resources/tags/water/*

I wish to change these to (remove the 'news')

*/resources/category/videos/*
*/resources/tags/water/*

Changing

`'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'resources/tags', 'with_front' => true ),`

to

`'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'resources/tags', 'with_front' => false ),`

returns a 404 error.

Full code as follows:

```
register_taxonomy( 'resource_category', array( 'resources' ), array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'labels'                 => array(
            'name'               => _x( 'Resource Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'      => _x( 'Resource Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        ),
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'resources/category', 'with_front' => true ),
    ) );

register_taxonomy( 'resource_tag', 'resources', array(
            'hierarchical'  => false,
            'labels'                 => array(
                'name'               => _x( 'Resource Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                'singular_name'      => _x( 'Resource Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            ),
            'show_ui'       => true,
            'query_var'     => true,
            'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'resources/tags', 'with_front' => true ),
    ) );

register_post_type( 'resources', array(
    'labels'                 => array(
        'name'               => __( 'Resources' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'Resource' ),
    ),
    'public'                => true,
    'menu_position'         => 20,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-media-document',
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'resources', 'with_front' => false ),
    'query_var'             => true,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'revisions' ),
    'taxonomies'            => array('resource_category', 'resource_tag'),
) );
```

With permalink setting structure
`/news/%postname%/`

Comment: Did you resave/flush your permalinks after making the change?

Comment: Yes, sure did...

Answer (score 0):

via: https://cnpagency.com/blog/the-right-way-to-do-wordpress-custom-taxonomy-rewrites/

I needed to change the order of registering the taxonomy (make sure it's before CPT) and the CPT (make sure it's after registering any taxonomy).

Now

`'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'resources/tags', 'with_front' => false ),`

works as expected!